# API design with conditional compilation: stubs and exceptions vs public API change?

Tags: c#, api-design, packages, unity3d

I am developing a package for the Unity game engine. I want to add additional functionality to my package if another specific package is present. I am faced with a dilemma I am not sure which of these two options is better in terms of API design and usability.

While not frequent, one can expect users to swap between having the other package installed or not. It would also be a fair assumption to say yet another third package might use my package as a dependency.

Thank you in advance for your thoughts and suggestions.

### 1. Stub values and exceptions

This option would mean the public API of my package won't change based on whether or not the user has the other package installed, but the values they would get would either be stubs or throw exceptions. Example:

```cs
public bool FooBar => 
#if OTHER_LIB_PRESENT
    OtherLib.Value();
#else
    false; // or throw an exception
#endif
```

### 2. Public API change

This option means the public API of my package would change depending on whether or not the user has the other package installed. Example:

```cs
#if OTHER_LIB_PRESENT
public bool FooBar => OtherLib.Value();
#endif
```

Comment: Both options sound like violating the [Principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).   Why not put this this decision into the hands of the users who are installing the package instead of trying to force the decision for them?   (i.e. if they have both packages installed, then simply give them a way to switch/choose in the code itself).  Perhaps as a configuration parameter or Startup option, to avoid forcing a 'silent' override; otherwise such silent alterations like this can cause developers to rip out their hair out in frustration.

Comment: @BenCottrell I actually don't quite understand the option you are suggesting. Would you mind elaborating a bit more?

Comment: @BenCottrell I believe I kind of understand it. So, in the tech stack I am working with, I can develop an additional package, which, when installed, would enable the conditional features. And users can choose to have it or not. But the problem I have with that is, if the other library (the `other_lib` condition) is present then it is almost a guarantee that the conditional features will be desired by the user, because they are very much interconnected.

Comment: @starikcetin no, not an additional package. Make it a configuration option that the developer can set. For example, if it's set it uses the `OtherLib.Value()`; if it's not it doesn't. And if it's set but they don't have `OtherLib` installed, an exception naturally gets thrown (`ModuleNotFoundException` or something like that)

Answer (score 2):

Neither option is good. Conditional compilation requires two sets of binaries, and just complicates the build process. Instead, declare an interface in your project that has the methods or properties your project needs, and give it a meaningful name:

```csharp
public interface ISomethingMeaningful
{
    bool Value();
}
```

Utilize the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) to provide a default implemendation:

```csharp
public DefaultSomethingMeaningful : ISomethingMeaningful
{
    public bool Value() => false;
}
```

Create a separate project providing an additional implementation of the interface for the other library:

```csharp
public class OtherLibSomethingMeaningful : ISomethingMeaningful
{
    public bool Value()
    {
        return // something that makes sense with this other library
    }
}
```

Classes that need this functionality should require an `ISomethingMeaningful` object in its constructor. You can provide the default implementation in constructors that do not declare an `ISomethingMeaningful` parameter:

```
public class Foo
{
    private ISomethingMeaningful Something { get; }

    // No null-checks or conditional compilation required
    public bool FooBar => Something.Value();

    public Foo() : this(new DefaultSomethingMeaningful())
    {
    }

    public Foo(ISomethingMeaningful something)
    {
        Something = something;
    }
}
```

This requires two projects, but gives other applications some flexibility, which is desirable in this case.